# How to cut faces away?

Tags: modeling, edges, faces

I have a cube and I want to cut along an edge so that I can move a face away from the cube.
[image]

Basically I want to make a cut along the orange selected closed line and at same time keeping all the faces (I just want to be able to move away faces without deforming the cube).

Note that my initial mesh is just a cube subdivided once, but seems the functions are a bit bugged:

Here's [what I tried so far](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21098/how-to-disconnect-selected-mesh-geometry):

---

**Attemp 1**

- Vertex Edit mode -> Edge Select -> Select ring to cut and press V

Don't work here's the result:
[image]

---

**Attemp 2**

- Vertex Edit mode -> Vertex Select -> Select vertices to make a ring and press Y

Don't work either here's the result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for linking. however both of the methods in that question don't work at all :(. I added both attemps to the question

Comment: In edit mode using “Face Select” select the four front faces. Press ”P” and choose "Selection" from the drop down menu.

Comment: Ah! I was moving the edge but not the center of the face! Thanks that did it.

Comment: I edited the duplicated answer to add the missing piece of information! :)

Comment: I'm surprised to see that you finally used the method which was written you'd like to avoid (seperating selection into new object). Both mentioned ways do work - splitting will split only selected geometry; ripping will create hole in the mesh on the selected edges.

Comment: I never written that I'd like to avoid a particular method. Can you quote the exact statement? O_O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In edit mode using “Face Select” select the four front faces. Press ”P” and choose "Selection" from the drop down menu.

Comment: This has the additional benefit (compared to the other answers in linked question) to move already stuff in another Object. Does that preserve smooth normals?

Comment: If the Normals are not facing the direction you want you can change that under the "Shading/UVs" tab in the tool bar.

Comment: You saved me hours :*