# Is there a way to unmerged two vertices in blender after merging them together?

Tags: modeling

I'm modeling am ear and after merging some points I realized I shouldn't have merged them I have done <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Z</kbd> but it could only take me so far.

How do I unmerge two vertices after merging them?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21098/how-to-disconnect-selected-mesh-geometry/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144828/is-it-possible-to-split-a-vertex/

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you might be looking for the Rip function.

In *Edit Mode*, pressing  <kbd>V</kbd> while vertex is selected will try to 'rip' them apart.